# Kubernetes nodes with low CPU utilisation

Tags: kubernetes, google-kubernetes-engine, autoscaling

I have a node pool for one deployment with 200-1000 pods. They're set with a CPU based HPA.
When the HPA scales down the deployment, it removes pods randomly, and eventually, I have an under-utilized node pool. The nodes aren't scaled down correctly because they still have at least one pod running.

I tried to find a solution and failed. Possible solutions, in my opinion:

1. HPA is aware of nodes utilization.
2. A PodDisruptionBudget for nodes?
3. Drain node if its CPU utilization is under a threshold.

Any help will be much appreciated.

Comment: All pods are the same application, or you have bunch of apps? Could you provide some details about your deployment config? I saw similar case about HPA downscale, did you see it? (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60846341/how-to-defrag-resource-utilization-of-gke-node-with-hpa-and-cluster-autoscaler)

Comment: What's the output of: kubectl describe -n kube-system configmap cluster-autoscaler-status ?